# How to link Single Contact to Multiple Account?

Tags: standard-objects, relationships

How can we link single contact to multiple Account. I have seen many links related to this issue but couldn't get any idea. Is there any work around for creating multiple Account for single Contact. Kindly advice me how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

With [`AccountContactRole`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrole.htm) object. It's a related list under Account, you might have it hidden on the page layout.

Check the help: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contactroles.htm and the [data model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm).

And also [Primary Contact for Account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9855/primary-contact-for-account) for some sample usage & considerations.

You will still need to populate `Contact.AccountId` with one of these accounts or it'll be considered a private contact (sharing rules don't work on private contacts so it'd be invisible for most of the users).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to create Validation rule, Trigger and custom fields for this Contact Role object? Do I need to create a record in Contact Role object as well while uploading the contact from Jitter bit.

Comment: No. Only thing you can control is the Role names. If you want more - you could create your own custom object with same purpose (lookup or master-detail relationship to Account, Contact, Role picklist and you're pretty much done). ("after insert" trigger on Contact to create the AccConRole isn't a problem). I'll try to call @techtrekker too, I think he had a great presentation about a viable Visualforce workaround, similar to https://www.youtube.com/embed/7QAWIPw5VIk

Comment: See also [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrBSAA0)

Answer (score 3):

The "Shared Contacts" feature is in **Pilot for Spring 15**. Until then, the best option is probably to create a join table, called for example Affiliations, that has two master-detail fields, one to Contact and one to Account.

Answer (score 2):

This is in limited use now but will roll out to sandboxes in May 2016.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrBSAA0

> Contacts to Multiple Accounts (fka Shared Contacts) will be generally available in the Summer 16 release!

Comment: This is fully supported as Contacts to Multiple Accounts.  See the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_accounts_contacts/admin_intro_accounts_contacts_relationships) on how to set it up